# concatenate text from a list based on another list

Tags: python, string, list

I have two lists, one of them is some lines, and the other is some values for these lines as follows:

```
text = ['Hello, ','I need some help in here ','things are not working well ','so i posted ','this question here ','hoping to get some ','good ','answers ','out of you ','that\'s it ','thanks']
value = [1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1]
```

**Goal** is to concatenate lines that meet the value `1` continuously, to get this result in any way possible:

```
['Hello ,I need some help in here ',
 'so i posted this question here hoping to get some',
 'answers out of you ',
 'thanks']
```

I tried to put it as a DataFrame but I then didn't know how to go on (using pandas in solution is not a must)

```
print(pd.DataFrame(data={"text":text,"value":value}))
                            text  value
0                        Hello,       1
1      I need some help in here       1
2   things are not working well       0
3                   so i posted       1
4            this question here       1
5            hoping to get some       1
6                          good       0
7                       answers       1
8                    out of you       1
9                     that's it       0
10                        thanks      1
```

Waiting for some Answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use Pandas:

```
tmp_str = ""
results = []
for chuck, is_evolved in zip(text, value):
    if is_evolved:
        tmp_str += chuck
    else:
        results.append(tmp_str)
        tmp_str = ""
if tmp_str:
    results.append(tmp_str)
print(results)
```

Comment: This is perfect, but can you explain it a little bit in case I needed to make some modifications?

Comment: please indicate which part to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `pandas` approach you can use [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`df.groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and `aggregate` by [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), and then access indices where `value` is 1:

```
>>> df.groupby(
            df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift(1)
            ).cumsum()
        ).transform(' '.join)[df['value'].eq(1)].drop_duplicates()
                                                 text
0                     Hello, I need some help in here
3   so i posted this question here hoping to get some
7                                  answers out of you
10                                             thanks
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
>>> df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift(1)).cumsum()
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     3
5     3
6     4
7     5
8     5
9     6
10    7
Name: value, dtype: int32

>>> df.groupby(df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift(1)).cumsum()).transform(' '.join)
                                                 text
0                     Hello, I need some help in here
1                     Hello, I need some help in here
2                         things are not working well
3   so i posted this question here hoping to get some
4   so i posted this question here hoping to get some
5   so i posted this question here hoping to get some
6                                                good
7                                  answers out of you
8                                  answers out of you
9                                           that's it
10                                             thanks
```

If you don't need a dataframe, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) over [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)ped values of `(text, value)` and groupby the second element, i.e. `value`. Then `str.join` groups' `text` part if `key == 1`.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [' '.join([*zip(*g)][0]) for k, g in groupby(zip(text, value), lambda x: x[1]) if k]
['Hello,  I need some help in here ',
 'so i posted  this question here  hoping to get some ',
 'answers  out of you ',
 'thanks']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Using pythonic *without* using `pandas`:

`text_ = [text[count] for count, n in enumerate(value) if n == 1]`

**Description**

This will take the list item in `text` at the `count` in the for loop if the list item in `value` equals `1`.

**Output**

```
['Hello, ', 'I need some help in here ', 'so i posted ', 'this question here ', 'hoping to get some ', 'answers ', 'out of you ', 'thanks']
```